# Change in atomic energy levels with motion

Tags: special-relativity, energy, electrons

How do the energy levels associated with electron orbitals in an atom change with the velocity of the atom?  If the atom is moving at, say 0.9c, will the difference between the 1st and 2nd energy levels differ from the same atom roughly at rest?

Answer (score -3):

You need to go back to the principle of relativity. Not even the fancy Einstein stuff, just the basics: "if things behave one way when at rest they must behave the same way when moving at a constant velocity" or "there is no way to discern the difference between an object moving at a constant velocity and the same object at rest."

According to the principle of relativity the only way different reference frames can disagree on energy differences is through the "boost," a factor that depends only on the relative speed. At low speeds this factor is negligible. At high relative speeds the factor is the "gamma" factor of relativity.

If you know the energy levels in one frame all you do is multiply by the boost factor to get the energy levels you'd see from a moving system.

For the particular relative speed of 0.95c the boost factor is $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.95^2} = 3.202$.

But again, this is nothing special about atoms, or electrons, or protons or anything. This is simply the math of how different reference frames come to agreement on energies.

["Galilean" low speed transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation)

[Lorentz "gamma" factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor)

[Lorentz transformation for high relative speeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#boost)

Comment: In the frame of the atom.

Comment: I'm talking about a frame in which the atom is moving at 0.9c (relative to a frame with an atom at rest).

Comment: Yes, in that frame the difference between the energy levels would be exactly the same as the frame in which the atom is at rest. That's the principle of relativity. Try taking the Hamiltonian for the Hydrogen atom and doing the frame transform $p \rightarrow p + mv$ and $r \rightarrow r \rightarrow r + vt$. You will get exactly the same Hamiltonian except for a constant term.

Comment: The wavelength of light you would see emitted from the atom as it moved by you would be different, but that's because of the Doppler effect, not because of anything different happening with the atom energy levels.

Comment: I suppose you can interpret the different wavelength as the energy levels being different. If you do so, the way to calculate the difference is to calculate the energies in the rest frame of the atom then Lorentz boost them to a moving frame. The energies all get the same $\gamma$ factor, so the energy differences also get a factor of $\gamma$. I've updated my answer to include this, but I think you should not get misled by it: there's no fundamental difference between a moving hydrogen atom and a non-moving hydrogen atom.

Comment: @LukePritchett ‘in that frame the difference between the energy levels would be exactly the same’ They would not.